# How to troubleshoot Cassandra not starting from Homebrew?

Tags: macos, cassandra, homebrew

When I try to start Cassandra with `brew services start cassandra`, I get a message that it has been successfully started. However, when I do `brew services list`, the Cassandra status is `started` but the `started` text is orange (not green).

It seems that Cassandra is not running at all. I am unable to connect to it with `cqlsh` and get no results when I run `ps aux | grep cass`.

Any suggestions how to troubleshoot Cassandra not starting from Homebrew?

Comment: is there anything in logs? I would recommend https://github.com/riptano/ccm if you want a cassandra cluster for development.

Comment: what Java version is installed?

Comment: @AlexOtt `java -version
java version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13-LTS, mixed mode)`

Comment: @ChrisLohfink I can't find any relevant logs. I have some cassandra logs, but they seem like output from when the instance was running. I haven't found any cassandra logs with any errors (much less errors on startup). I imagine these startup errors may be in some Homebrew logs, but I haven't found them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a problem with Java version - existing releases of the Cassandra do work only with Java 8. Support for Java 9,10,11, ... is added only in Cassandra 4.0 that isn't released yet.  You need to install Java 8 and point Cassandra to it.

You can read more about the changes in following [blog post](http://thelastpickle.com/blog/2018/08/16/java11.html).